# problems with installing a new outlet!

Tags: electrical

I sure am glad for a site like this.....THANK You!!!  I am a DIY'r and can usually figure things out, but this has me scratching my head! I cannot fit the electrical wires from the wall into the new outlet! The back of the new outlet says to "press to release" (located on the back of outlet), but there is nothing to press! I understand how to do everything I just cannot figure out how to get the wires to fit in the outlet!!I'm sure I will be very embarrassed once someone tells me how to do it, but I'm willing to take the chance, I need my outlet!!!lol, Thank you for your help.

Comment: Think I figured it out!!!! instead of fitting them in the hole I'm gonna wrap them around the screws!!!!! Thanks everyone

Comment: For future reference: To get better answers faster, make your questions easy to read. Almost none of those exclamation points are needed or appropriate; it reads as if you are shouting at us, and nobody likes being shouted at.

Comment: But they're like sparkly and stuff!!!!!!1 Seriously Cindi, you are on the right track making a hook around the screw.  Most of us dislike those push-in jab connections (aka backstabs).  They are ok if they involve tightening the screw down to clamp the wire, but those are on the $3-4 outlets not the 60 cent ones.

Answer (score 2):

Use the side screws -- the old style "back-stab" terminations are rather unreliable critters (they have a habit of failing to a high-resistance state).  Also, 12 gauge wire won't fit into the backstabs, but is fine with the side screws.

Comment: Also stabs are for 14 gauge 12 won't fit and the screws need to be used. +